# Running ANTRL TestRig GUI from within a Java application

Tags: java, eclipse, antlr, antlr4

I know it's possible to generate a graphical representation of a parse tree using ANTLR's TestRig "grun" through the terminal:

```
$ alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig'​​
$ grun Example test -gui
hello world
​​​​E​O​F​​​​
```

But is it possible to call the TestRig from within a Java application? I want to make use of the TestRig capabilities to make a Java application that takes the user input and shows the generated parse tree graphical representation.

I already tried the following:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig;
...
TestRig test = new TestRig(args);
test.process();
```

But I got this message:

> Can't load Example as lexer or parser

It looks it should work, because it correctly identified the arguments `Example test -gui` I set on Eclipse, but the TestRig does not seem to be able to find the grammar.

How do I set up the arguments properly? And if that's not possible, is there any other way of running ANTLR's TestRig inside a Java application?

Comment: Have you tried running your java code from command line after setting export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" ? Please change location of antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar as necessary in your case. If it runs from command line then may be its only some sort of issue in your eclipse setup

Comment: Yes, I've set the class path, but running the application from command line get's the same result. I did put all my java classes in the same package but it did not help.

Comment: If you look at the source code of TestRig then it clearly looks like the class loading issue. All I can suggest here is to keep digging on those lines.

Comment: So you're saying that the problem is inherent from the TestRig class itself? Were can I see it's source code?

Comment: I did not intend to mean that there is any problem with TestRig class. I meant that it has the logic of loading the class. Here is the source code of TestRig https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/misc/TestRig.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I've solved my issue. By looking at the source code of the TestRig class, I've found that I just needed to use the inspect() method to generate the GUI view. Here's an example code:

```
// Create an input stream that receives text from the terminal
ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);

// Create an Lexer that receives the char stream
ExampleLexer lexer = new ExampleLexer(input);

// Create a token stream from the lexer
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

// Create a parser that receives the token stream
ExampleParser parser = new ExampleParser(tokens);

// Create a parser tree starting from the first rule
TestContext tree = parser.test();

//Generates the GUI
tree.inspect(parser);
```

EDIT: As for version 4.5.1, the code that generates the tree changes to this:

```
//Generates the GUI
Trees.inspect(tree, parser);
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet works for me (antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar):

```
void showGuiTreeView(final String code)
{
    final org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream stream = new ANTLRInputStream(code);
    final MyLexer lexer = new MyLexer(stream);
    final CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    final MyParser parser = new MyParser(tokens);
    final ParseTree tree = parser.expr();
    final List<String> ruleNames = Arrays.asList(MyParser.ruleNames);
    final TreeViewer view = new TreeViewer(ruleNames, tree);
    view.open();
}
```